# sha512 implementation c++ (made for learning purposes) doesn't generate temp1 value but gives a wierdly similar answer

Tags: c++, loops, cryptography, sha512, hexdump

if you look at the temp1 value in iteration 0. You will see that I'm getting 0xb37b0cfa1b96e8a0 while I should be getting 0x1b37b0cfa1b96e8a0. why is the 0x1 not appearing in mine? Is this a datatype-related issue? does it overflow or is my implementation for temp1 wrong?

I hashed "abc" by the way.

to hash a message: `SHA512 hash("abc");`

Code:

```
/*
 *  github: kibnakamoto
 *   Created on: Dec. 5, 2021
 *      Author: Taha Canturk
 *        More Info: github.com/kibnakamoto/sha512.cpp/blob/main/README.md
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdint.h>

// choice = (x ∧ y) ⊕ (¯x ∧ z)
inline uint64_t Ch(uint64_t e, uint64_t f, uint64_t g) {
    return ((e bitand f)xor(~e bitand g));
}
// #define Ch(x,y,z) ((x bitand y)xor(~x bitand z))

// // majority = (x ∧ y) ⊕ (x ∧ z) ⊕ (y ∧ z)
inline uint64_t Maj(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c) {
    return ((a & b)^(a & c)^(b & c));
}

// // binary operators
inline uint64_t Shr(uint64_t x, unsigned int n) {
    return (x >> n);
}
inline uint64_t Rotr(uint64_t x, unsigned int n) {
    return ( (x >> n)|(x << (sizeof(x)<<3)-n) );
}

// length which is __uint128_t in 2 uint64_t integers
inline std::pair<uint64_t,uint64_t> to2_uint64(__uint128_t source) {
    constexpr const __uint128_t bottom_mask = (__uint128_t{1} << 64) - 1;
    constexpr const __uint128_t top_mask = ~bottom_mask;
    return {source bitand bottom_mask, Shr((source bitand top_mask), 64)};
}

class SHA512
{
    protected:
        uint64_t W[80];
        
        // 80 64 bit unsigned constants for sha512 algorithm
        const uint64_t K[80] =
        {
            0x428a2f98d728ae22ULL, 0x7137449123ef65cdULL, 0xb5c0fbcfec4d3b2fULL,
            0xe9b5dba58189dbbcULL, 0x3956c25bf348b538ULL, 0x59f111f1b605d019ULL,
            0x923f82a4af194f9bULL, 0xab1c5ed5da6d8118ULL, 0xd807aa98a3030242ULL,
            0x12835b0145706fbeULL, 0x243185be4ee4b28cULL, 0x550c7dc3d5ffb4e2ULL,
            0x72be5d74f27b896fULL, 0x80deb1fe3b1696b1ULL, 0x9bdc06a725c71235ULL,
            0xc19bf174cf692694ULL, 0xe49b69c19ef14ad2ULL, 0xefbe4786384f25e3ULL,
            0x0fc19dc68b8cd5b5ULL, 0x240ca1cc77ac9c65ULL, 0x2de92c6f592b0275ULL, 
            0x4a7484aa6ea6e483ULL, 0x5cb0a9dcbd41fbd4ULL, 0x76f988da831153b5ULL,
            0x983e5152ee66dfabULL, 0xa831c66d2db43210ULL, 0xb00327c898fb213fULL,
            0xbf597fc7beef0ee4ULL, 0xc6e00bf33da88fc2ULL, 0xd5a79147930aa725ULL,
            0x06ca6351e003826fULL, 0x142929670a0e6e70ULL, 0x27b70a8546d22ffcULL,
            0x2e1b21385c26c926ULL, 0x4d2c6dfc5ac42aedULL, 0x53380d139d95b3dfULL,
            0x650a73548baf63deULL, 0x766a0abb3c77b2a8ULL, 0x81c2c92e47edaee6ULL,
            0x92722c851482353bULL, 0xa2bfe8a14cf10364ULL, 0xa81a664bbc423001ULL,
            0xc24b8b70d0f89791ULL, 0xc76c51a30654be30ULL, 0xd192e819d6ef5218ULL,
            0xd69906245565a910ULL, 0xf40e35855771202aULL, 0x106aa07032bbd1b8ULL,
            0x19a4c116b8d2d0c8ULL, 0x1e376c085141ab53ULL, 0x2748774cdf8eeb99ULL,
            0x34b0bcb5e19b48a8ULL, 0x391c0cb3c5c95a63ULL, 0x4ed8aa4ae3418acbULL,
            0x5b9cca4f7763e373ULL, 0x682e6ff3d6b2b8a3ULL, 0x748f82ee5defb2fcULL,
            0x78a5636f43172f60ULL, 0x84c87814a1f0ab72ULL, 0x8cc702081a6439ecULL,
            0x90befffa23631e28ULL, 0xa4506cebde82bde9ULL, 0xbef9a3f7b2c67915ULL,
            0xc67178f2e372532bULL, 0xca273eceea26619cULL, 0xd186b8c721c0c207ULL,
            0xeada7dd6cde0eb1eULL, 0xf57d4f7fee6ed178ULL, 0x06f067aa72176fbaULL,
            0x0a637dc5a2c898a6ULL, 0x113f9804bef90daeULL, 0x1b710b35131c471bULL,
            0x28db77f523047d84ULL, 0x32caab7b40c72493ULL, 0x3c9ebe0a15c9bebcULL,
            0x431d67c49c100d4cULL, 0x4cc5d4becb3e42b6ULL, 0x597f299cfc657e2aULL,
            0x5fcb6fab3ad6faecULL, 0x6c44198c4a475817ULL};
        uint64_t H[8] = {
            0x6a09e667f3bcc908ULL, 0xbb67ae8584caa73bULL,
            0x3c6ef372fe94f82bULL, 0xa54ff53a5f1d36f1ULL,
            0x510e527fade682d1ULL, 0x9b05688c2b3e6c1fULL,
            0x1f83d9abfb42bd6bULL, 0x5be0cd19137e2179ULL
        };
        
    public:
        /* default class constructor */
        SHA512(std::string msg)
        {
            // length in bytes.
            __uint128_t len = msg.length();
            
            // length is represented by a 128 bit unsigned integer
            __uint128_t bitlen = len << 3;
            
            // padding with zeros
            unsigned int padding = ((1024-(bitlen+1)-128) % 1024)-7;
            padding /= 8; // in bytes.
            unsigned int blockBytesLen = padding+len+17;
            uint8_t WordArray[blockBytesLen];
            memset(WordArray, 0, blockBytesLen);
            for (__uint128_t c=0;c<len;c++) {
                WordArray[c] = msg.c_str()[c];
            }
            WordArray[len] = (uint8_t)0x80ULL; // append 10000000.
            
            // pad W with zeros
            for (int c=0; c<80; c++) {
                W[c] = 0x00ULL;
            }
            
            // add WordArray to W array
            // 8 bit array values to 64 bit array using 64 bit integer pointer.
            for (__uint128_t i=0; i<len/8+1; i++) {
                W[i] = (uint64_t)WordArray[i*8]<<56;
                for (int j=1; j<=6; j++)
                    W[i] = W[i]|( (uint64_t)WordArray[i*8+j]<<(7-j)*8);
                W[i] = W[i]|( (uint64_t)WordArray[i*8+7] );
            }
            
            // append 128 bit length as 2 uint64_t's as a big endian
            auto [fst, snd] = to2_uint64(bitlen);
            W[Shr(padding+len+1,3)+1] = fst;
            W[Shr(padding+len+1,3)+2] = snd;
            
            // create message schedule
            for (int c=16;c<80;c++)
            {
                // σ0 = (w[c−15] ≫≫ 1) ⊕ (w[c−15] ≫≫ 8) ⊕ (w[c−15] ≫ 7)
                uint64_t s0 = Rotr(W[c-15],1) xor Rotr(W[c-15],8) xor Shr(W[c-15],7);
                
                // σ1 = (w[c−2] ≫≫ 19) ⊕ (w[c−2] ≫≫ 61) ⊕ (w[c−2] ≫ 6)
                uint64_t s1 = Rotr(W[c-2],19) xor Rotr(W[c-2],61) xor Shr(W[c-2],6);
                
                // uint64_t does binary addition 2^64.
                // w[c] = w[c−16] [+] σ0 [+] w[c−7] [+] σ1
                W[c] = W[c-16] + s0 + W[c-7] + s1;
            }
            uint64_t V[8]; // initialize hash values
            memcpy(V, H, sizeof(uint64_t)*8);
            
            // transform
            for (int c=0;c<80;c++)
            {
                // Σ0 = (a ≫≫ 28) ⊕ (a ≫≫ 34) ⊕ (a ≫≫ 39)
                uint64_t S0 = Rotr(V[0], 28) xor Rotr(V[0], 34) xor Rotr(V[0], 39);

                // T2 = Σ0 + Maj
                uint64_t temp2 = S0 + Maj(V[0], V[1], V[2]);
                
                // Σ1 = (e ≫≫ 14) ⊕ (e ≫≫ 18) ⊕ (e ≫≫ 41)
                uint64_t S1 = Rotr(V[4], 14) xor Rotr(V[4], 18) xor Rotr(V[4], 41);

                // T1 = h + Σ1 + Ch[e,f,g] + K[c] + W[c]
                uint64_t temp1 = V[7] + S1 + Ch(V[4], V[5], V[6]) + K[c] + W[c];

                // modify hash values
                V[7] = V[6];
                V[6] = V[5];
                V[5] = V[4];
                V[4] = V[3] + temp1;
                V[3] = V[2];
                V[2] = V[1];
                V[1] = V[0];
                V[0] = temp1 + temp2;

                /* ================== per-iteration values ================== */
                std::cout << "iteration round: " << std::dec << c << std::endl;
                std::cout << "a: " << std::hex << V[0] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "b: " << std::hex << V[1] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "c: " << std::hex << V[2] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "d: " << std::hex << V[3] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "e: " << std::hex << V[4] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "f: " << std::hex << V[5] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "g: " << std::hex << V[6] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "h: " << std::hex << V[7] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "S0:\t" << std::hex << S0 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "S1:\t" << std::hex << S1 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "t0:\t" << std::hex << temp2 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "t1:\t" << std::hex << temp1 << std::endl;

            }
            
            // final values
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
            for (int c=0;c<8;c++)
            {
                H[c] += V[c];
                std::cout << std::hex << H[c];
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::string msg;
    msg = "abc";
    // std::cout << "input:\t";
    // getline(std::cin, msg);
    SHA512 hash(msg);
    std::cout << std::endl
          << "ddaf35a193617abacc417349ae20413112e6fa4e89a97ea20a9ee"
          <<"ee64b55d39a2192992a274fc1a836ba3c23a3feebbd454d442364"
          << "3ce80e2a9ac94fa54ca49f\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t^ correct value ^";
    return 0;
}
```

The rest of the implementation seems to be correct but the temp1 value isn't. I think it might be required for temp1 to be a 128-bit int but the size of the correct value is still 64 bit so I'm really confused about how I'm getting 0xb37b0cfa1b96e8a0 instead of 0x1b37b0cfa1b96e8a0. the only difference is that the correct value starts with an extra 1(in hexadecimal).

edit: I used test vectors and other example codes that work to see that I did everything right including the message schedule but haven't got the right answer for temp1. the rest of the code seems to be working(at least for a single block).

the code that isn't working well:

```
            // transform
            for (int c=0;c<80;c++)
            {
                // Σ0 = (a ≫≫ 28) ⊕ (a ≫≫ 34) ⊕ (a ≫≫ 39)
                uint64_t S0 = Rotr(V[0], 28) xor Rotr(V[0], 34) xor Rotr(V[0], 39);

                // T2 = Σ0 + Maj
                uint64_t temp2 = S0 + Maj(V[0], V[1], V[2]);
                
                // Σ1 = (e ≫≫ 14) ⊕ (e ≫≫ 18) ⊕ (e ≫≫ 41)
                uint64_t S1 = Rotr(V[4], 14) xor Rotr(V[4], 18) xor Rotr(V[4], 41);

                // T1 = h + Σ1 + Ch[e,f,g] + K[c] + W[c]
                uint64_t temp1 = V[7] + S1 + Ch(V[4], V[5], V[6]) + K[c] + W[c];

                // modify hash values
                V[7] = V[6];
                V[6] = V[5];
                V[5] = V[4];
                V[4] = V[3] + temp1;
                V[3] = V[2];
                V[2] = V[1];
                V[1] = V[0];
                V[0] = temp1 + temp2;

                /* ================== per-iteration values ================== */
                std::cout << "iteration round: " << std::dec << c << std::endl;
                std::cout << "a: " << std::hex << V[0] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "b: " << std::hex << V[1] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "c: " << std::hex << V[2] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "d: " << std::hex << V[3] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "e: " << std::hex << V[4] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "f: " << std::hex << V[5] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "g: " << std::hex << V[6] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "h: " << std::hex << V[7] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "S0:\t" << std::hex << S0 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "S1:\t" << std::hex << S1 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "t0:\t" << std::hex << temp2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: I've been looking forward to finishing this code today but can't figure this part out.

Comment: Is there any reason for those various operations to be `#define`s and not ordinary functions? In particular it looks like `Shr(padding+len+1, 3)` is likely to be misbehaving. Although actually binary `+` has higher precedence than binary `>>` but still. Seems weird.

Comment: In `for (int c=0;c<len;c++)` are you really sure you want `c` to be compared against the  128 bit unsigned int `len`? Odds are really good that `len` can be far larger than `c` can ever reach.

Comment: Anyway a more central point is that this question would be significantly improved by paring it down to a _minimal_ reproducible example. If you have a bunch of code that you think is working fine, excise it so people can focus on the parts that might be misbehaving. The process of doing so might even lead you to finding out where the bug lies.

Comment: Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to perform some boundary tests on the functions, especially functions such as ROTR, which are easy to implement incorrectly and easy to verify. You could also think of extracting some functions from the overall SHA - if you want to have highest performance you can always inline them again at a later stage.

Comment: answer for @NathanPierson Pierson - I used macros because I didn't want to use too many lines. for inline functions. so there isn't a reason why it has to be macros.

Comment: answer for @user4581301 - that seems to be my mistake. I will fix it.

Comment: I added the whole code because if anyone wants to run the code. They could.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - I couldn't verify if the compile time of inline functions were faster than macros so I used macros because I don't have to verify type so it will be shorter. If so, I will convert them into inline functions.

Comment: I now converted macros to inline

Comment: Matt Godbolt's [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) is a good tool for seeing the nitty-gritty stuff like whether a function was inlined or not. That said, if you profile and can't see the difference, why would you care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two bugs that I've found.  The first is in the initial value of G.  You provided 0x1f83d9abfb42bd6b, but 0x1f83d9abfb41bd6b is correct (that is `41`, not `42`).  Because SHA-512, like all cryptographically secure hash functions, exhibits the [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect), changing the initial constant by even one bit will result in a totally different output.  This change probably does not affect the security of the algorithm, but of course it's not SHA-512 and doesn't produce compatible results.

My recommendation in this case is to copy and paste the constants from the PDF or other reputable source, or generate them at the command line using `bc` or `dc`, since this kind of mistake is easy to make.  The constants aren't copyrightable anyway, so copying and pasting a list of them from somewhere doesn't affect the license of your code.

The other, once that's fixed, is that `std::hex` doesn't format to two places, so when one of the output bytes ix 0x0a, it just prints "a" instead of "0a".  I know there's some way to fix this using the standard formatting streams in C++, but I've virtually abandoned C++ for Rust some time ago, so I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader.  You could also just use (gasp!) `printf`, where the `%02x` format specifier will do what you want.

I discovered the problem by using the outputs in the [NIST intermediate values PDF](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/SHA512.pdf) and then comparing constants to see what was different.